# How to apply an XSLT template to a node copy using variable conditions (extracted from a previous XML node)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new to XSLT transformations. I am writing some transformations in order to refactor code expressed in srcML and I am facing a problem. The XML input I am working with looks like this:

```xml
....
<function><type><name>void</name></type> <name>DrawHorizontal</name>
<parameter_list>(
    <param><decl><type><name>t_paper</name></type> <name>p</name></decl></param>,
    <param><decl><type><name>int</name></type> <name>x</name></decl></param>,
    <param><decl><type><name>int</name></type> <name>y</name></decl></param>)
 </parameter_list>
   <block>{.....
     <expr_stmt><expr>
       <name>
         <name>p</name>
         <index>[<expr><name>x</name></expr>]</index>
         <index>[<expr><name>y</name></expr>]</index>
       </name>.
       <name>hor</name>
       <operator>=</operator> 1
     </expr>;</expr_stmt>
  ...
  }</block>
</function>
```

What I want to do is, for each function section:

1) Identify the name of the parameters of a certain type (p of type t_paper for example)

2) Change the expression statement where the parameters, identified in the previous step, are found ()

The output should look like this:

```xml
.....
<function><type><name>void</name></type> <name>DrawHorizontal</name>
<parameter_list>(
    <param><decl><type><name>t_paper</name></type> <name>p</name></decl></param>,
    <param><decl><type><name>int</name></type> <name>x</name></decl></param>,
    <param><decl><type><name>int</name></type> <name>y</name></decl></param>)
 </parameter_list>
   <block>{.....
     <expr_stmt><expr>
       <name>p</name>.
       <name>
         <name>data</name>
         <index>[<expr><name>x</name></expr>]</index>
         <index>[<expr><name>y</name></expr>]</index>
       </name>.
       <name>hor</name>
       <operator>=</operator> 1
     </expr>;</expr_stmt>
  ...
  }</block>
</function>
```

In summary, I need to transform expr_stmt nodes only where parameters of a certain type are found (t_paper in the example). The rest of the file should be copied as it is.

My problem is that I am not able to apply templates to that specific sections based on the dynamically created conditions (the names of the parameters).

Some NOT working code is the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//function">
<xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="parameter_list/param/decl/type/name='t_paper'">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:call-template name="transform-function" select="node()">
      <xsl:with-param name="appearance" select="parameter_list/param/decl/name" />
     </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy> 
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
         <function><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></function>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="transform-function">
<xsl:param name="appearance" />
<xsl:if test="//expr_stmt/expr/name/name=$appearance">
    substitution here
</xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would be very grateful if someone could give me a hint.

Please let me know if you need more details as this is my first question in SO.

Cheers,

D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This simple transformation** (no explicit conditionals at all):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kParamByNameType" match="param"
  use="concat(decl/name, '+', decl/type/name)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "expr/name
         [key('kParamByNameType',
              concat(name, '+', 't_paper')
              )
         ]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
  <name>
    <name>data</name>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name/following-sibling::node()"/>
  </name>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<function>
    <type>
        <name>void</name>
    </type>
    <name>DrawHorizontal</name>
    <parameter_list>(     
        <param>
           <decl>
                    <type>
                        <name>t_paper</name>
                    </type>
                    <name>p</name>
       </decl>
        </param>,     
        <param>
            <decl>
                <type>
                    <name>int</name>
                </type>
                <name>x</name>
            </decl>
        </param>,     
        <param>
            <decl>
                <type>
                    <name>int</name>
                </type>
                <name>y</name>
            </decl>
        </param>)  
    </parameter_list>
    <block>{.....      
        <expr_stmt>
            <expr>
                <name>
                    <name>p</name>
                    <index>[
                        <expr>
                            <name>x</name>
                        </expr>]
                    </index>
                    <index>[
                        <expr>
                            <name>y</name>
                        </expr>]
                    </index></name>.        
                <name>hor</name>
                <operator>=</operator> 1      
            </expr>;
        </expr_stmt>   ...   }
    </block>
</function>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<function>
   <type>
      <name>void</name>
   </type>
   <name>DrawHorizontal</name>
   <parameter_list>(     
        <param>
         <decl>
            <type>
               <name>t_paper</name>
            </type>
            <name>p</name>
         </decl>
      </param>,     
        <param>
         <decl>
            <type>
               <name>int</name>
            </type>
            <name>x</name>
         </decl>
      </param>,     
        <param>
         <decl>
            <type>
               <name>int</name>
            </type>
            <name>y</name>
         </decl>
      </param>)  
    </parameter_list>
   <block>{.....      
        <expr_stmt>
         <expr>
            <name>p</name>
            <name>
               <name>data</name>
               <index>[
                        <expr>
                     <name>x</name>
                  </expr>]
                    </index>
               <index>[
                        <expr>
                     <name>y</name>
                  </expr>]
                    </index>
            </name>.        
                <name>hor</name>
            <operator>=</operator> 1      
            </expr>;
        </expr_stmt>   ...   }
    </block>
</function>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **Overriding the [identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) just for parameters that are of the requested type.**
2. **Using a [key](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)** to conveniently define the mapping between a parameter declaration and its (name, type)

Comment: I'm sure it works, but you posted the output XML without the .data in it ;)

Comment: @memetech: Thank you for notifying me -- I hadn't even noticed the `<name>data</name>`. Now added.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dimitre, great answer. It works perfectly, I did not know the existence of keys. I am really thankful. D.

Comment: Hi again, everything is working fine but now I am getting a compile error when trying to use an input parameter (using xsltproc --stringparam type "t_paper" ...) in the key() function like this: key('nameofthekey', $type). The error is: **xsltCompilePattern : failed to compile 'key('nameofthekey', $type)'** Any idea?

Comment: ok, this is solved. It was of course due to the fact that xslt 1.0 does not allow variables within the match expression

Comment: @Ddd: You are welcome. And no, variables *are* allowed in the `key()` function (the bolded example from your comment). In XSLT 1.0 variables aren't allowed in the definition of a key -- in the `match` attribute of `<xsl:key>`

Answer (score 0):

**This is an xsl:key element/key() function answer**

I had to step back from your two step solution to find a workable answer. I don't know where you're getting your expression statement from, but I suppose it is something from C#/.NET.

In any case I see that what you are doing is wrapping a type so that the expressions change from:

```
p[x][y] to p.data[x][y]
```

If that's the case, instead of applying different appearances to the overall function, I chose to just have templates match on components of the expression. Then conditionally on each parameter name, I lookup the type to see if it is the one you are looking for. Additional 'when' statements can be added for each type you want to catch:

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--  key('parambyname','p')/type/name eq 't_paper' -->
<xsl:key name="parambyname" match="parameter_list/param/decl" use="name"/>

<xsl:template match="//expr_stmt/expr//name">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="key('parambyname',text())/type/name eq 't_paper'">
       <xsl:copy>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="./text()" />
       </xsl:copy>
       <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
       <name>data</name>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="!text()"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
       </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @@memetech: This code isn't compliant XSLT (neither 1.0 or 2.0). Please, run your solution (and if necessary correct) before posting it. I also made an obvious correction, then run it only to find that the produced output was *not* the wanted one.

Comment: I developed and ran the solution using WMHelp's XMLPad 3.0 before posting it. I verified again that it has no problem with MSXML30, MSXML40 or it's own internal transform engine. There are no validation errors. If there is a problem with it against the XSLT specs it obviously doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: Ok calm down, I just told you what tool I used. Can't you assume that the tool is allowing those extensions rather than that the user of the tool is inherently a base and evil person, out to defraud the system and attack you personally ?

Comment: If anyone actually tries to use this code, I will more than happily support them. The two instances of non-compliance with the spec are easily fixed using `not()` instead of `!`, and using `=` instead of `eq`. If that's a big deal to you, use the solution proposed by  @DimitreNovatchev

Comment: @@memetech: This question is tagged with `xslt`, `xpath` and `xml`. Anyone reading questions and answers in these tags expects *compliant* XSLT code and *compliant* XPath expressions -- not something that is accepted by a weird tool. Your statement that this code "has no problem with MSXML30, MSXML40"  is a lie that anyone can see by trying to run the code with either of these XSLT processors.

Comment: Look, I've acknowledged your complaint, accepted your -1, and have addressed the specific violations you brought up. I wrote the answer in parallel with you, using a different tool, tested it, and got my answer in first.  I feel this answer is as valid as yours, and obviously since we both answered we cannot claim to be unbiased. You've stated your case, I've stated mine, please (please!) now let the community decide.

Comment: @@memetech: It is not possible to determine unambiguously how to map code with illegal syntax with proper one -- I tried this with your uncompliant code long ago. The result was syntactically correct code that produced something different from the wanted answer. Maybe there are other possible interpretations of your broken code and even maybe one of these could produce the desired result... Do you see what the problem is? Instead of providing an answer to the original problem, you are giving the reader another problem -- to decipher illegal code. I would -1 this again if this were possible.

Comment: @@memetech: It is not possible to determine unambiguously how to map code with illegal syntax with proper one -- I tried this with your uncompliant code long ago. The result was syntactically correct code that produced something different from the wanted answer. Maybe there are other possible interpretations of your broken code and even maybe one of these could produce the desired result... Do you see what the problem is? Instead of providing an answer to the original problem, you are giving the reader another problem -- to decipher your illegal code. I'd -1 this again if this were possible.

Comment: @memetech, just accept that Dimitre only considers that his opinion is ever correct. He's already told me that I shouldn't be in the industry because of my opinion on an issue.